# What's the standard way of implementing an automaton with not-transitions?

Tags: regex, finite-automata, deterministic

The naive implementation of a FA would have the node look like:

```
struct Node {
    string label;
    Node*[char] trans;
}
```

But what if one of your transitions is "![a]" (anything but the char 'a').  And your alphabet is too huge to store all possible chars that are not 'a'.  Do you see what I mean?

Edit.  My current guess is

```
struct NFAState {
    string label;
    Node*[][char] trans;
    Node*[][char] notTrans;
    Node*[] epsTrans;
}
```

for an NFA node.

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++?

Comment: D.  Node*[char] is a built-in hash-table associative array.  So trans['a'] will point to the state given the current node and input 'a'.

Comment: What about storing `-'a'` in the original struct design? Do you also thought about the hardcoded FA? Or if the FA is acyclic, you can use bitstream implementation.

Comment: @bartimar: What do you mean by bitstream impl?

Comment: I see what you mean, from a paper.  I guess I will save that idea for the DFA.  NFA useage would mean in multiple states at once, which wouldn't take advantage of the ordering of states in memory.

Comment: Oh, I thought we are talking about DFA all the time :) sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a second `Node*[char] notTrans;` and store all nodes for the not cases.

Comment: We were on the same wavelength.